# How to solve a DC (Difference of Convex) program?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, non-convex

I have an objective function which is the difference of two convex functions in **Tensorflow** and I want to minimize it. Formally, I have the following problem:

$\text{min}_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \;\;f(x)-g(x)$

where both $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are convex over domain $\mathcal{X}$.

I would like to know what is the best way (the easiest way) to solve this in Tensorflow ?
Is it possible to simply use a stochastic gradient descent algorithm to find a local optimum ? or maybe L-BFGS-B  method ?

Thanks

Comment: If you solve the problem using (stochastic) gradient descent or L-BFGS-B, they will just treat it as a generic non-convex problem rather than exploiting special structure of DC. DC-specific approach would successively linearize the concave portion, i.e., -g(x), or perhaps successively approximate with some convex function other than linear, and is predicated on using a good convex solver to solve the resulting convex problems. That may or may not be better than L-BFGS-B.  Don't know what possibilities are under Tensorflow. Can you say what your f(x) and g(x) are? How about constraints, if any?

Comment: At this stage I do not have any constraint. both $f$ and $g$ are in the form of log-sum-exponentials.

Comment: What's the dimension of your problem?  Have you seen anything which suggests DC works well when g(x) is logsumexp? What is the dimension of x?

Comment: My problem is just a toy example and is fairly small. I have not seen anything like DC works for well for ....

Comment: There was recently a whole journal issue devoted to DC Programming. https://link.springer.com/journal/10107/169/1/page/1 Mathematical Programming Volume 169, Issue 1, May 2018 Special Issue: DC Programming - Theory, Algorithms and Applications

Comment: What seems good?

Comment: The link that you sent and the papers there. I am trying to find them on arxiv.